# Using JavaScript components/plugins in an Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, tinymce

Everything that I have learned so far about Angular tells me *not* to manipulate the DOM directly, which is understandable given how the framework operates.  Is it safe to use external JavaScript components such as TinyMCE [as described here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/#) in an Angular application?  If so, could someone please explain why?  I have been asked to investigate this topic, but so far have not been able to find anything beyond "don't touch the DOM".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to include a javascript library which depends on direct DOM manipulation, you can encapsulate it within a component or a directive. It can modify this part of the DOM as it wishes.

You can use the various Angular component lifecycle hooks, to perform setup and teardown of the third party library.

Data that is relevant to the third party library can be passed in through `@Input()` parameters.

If you need to continuously pass data to the library you could pass it an Observable which represents a stream of the relevant state.

The third party component can communicate with the Angular world through one or more EventEmitters (`@Output()`).

Things get tricky when other parts of the DOM are manipulated by the library.

---

Edit:

For an example on how to use the [Split.js](https://nathancahill.github.io/Split.js/) library with Angular, checkout this plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/qGyQWUz16Z2PY1kFUXyt/

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So if the functionality is limited to the specific plugin, such as an editor, then it is "safe"?  What if I wanted to use other custom JS libraries, such as a select menu or resizable split panels that are more basic elements in an Angular app?

Comment: I've added a plunker to show how to use a split panel library with Angular. You can add more third party functionality inside e.g. the panels without any issues. Only when the children begin to modify their parent containers, things can get messy.

Comment: Great!  Thanks for your help.